# $K_{11}$ covered by pentagons such that...

Tags: graph-theory

Can the complete graph on $11$ vertices, $K_{11}$, be covered by pentagons, such that each pair of pentagons shares exactly two points (and no edges.)

If we drop the restriction that each pair shares exactly 2 points, it can be done. Take the pentagon $\{1,2,5,9,7 \}$ and generate the rest by adding $1$ to each value, and so on, taking the values mod $11$.

Comment: Note that to identify a pentagon not only the vertices but the order in which they should be connected must be given.

Comment: Right, I know curly brackets look like a set, but interpret them in the order they are given.

Comment: I thought I understood the rules but now I'm not sure. Is it OK if the first pentagon is $(1,2,3,4,5)$ and the second is $(1,6,2,7,8)$? The pentagons share exactly two points, namely the points $1$ and $2$; and they share no edges, the first pentagon having edges $12,23,34,45,15$ and the second $16,26,27,78,18.$

Comment: @bof That is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematica's clique-finding algorithm says that one such set of pentagons is
$$(1,2,3,4,5) \quad (1,3,6,7,8) \quad (1,7,10,2,9) \quad (1,4,8,9,11) \\ (1,6,11,5,10) \quad (2,6,9,3,11) \quad (2,4,10,6,8) \quad (2,5,8,11,7) \\ (3,7,4,11,10) \quad (3,5,9,10,8) \quad (4,6,5,7,9).$$

So that this answer has some content to it, here's my Mathematica code.

```
subsets = Subsets[Range[11], {5}];
pents[s_] := Select[Permutations[s], #[[1]] == Min[#] && #[[2]] < #[[5]] &]
pentagons = Flatten[pents /@ subsets, 1];
adjacentQ[p1_, p2_] := 
  Length@Intersection[p1, p2] == 2 && 
  Length@Intersection[Sort /@ Partition[p1, 2, 1, 1], Sort /@ Partition[p2, 2, 1, 1]] == 0

first = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
second = {1, 3, 6, 7, 8};

rest = Select[pentagons, adjacentQ[#, first] && adjacentQ[#, second] &];
edges = #[[1]] <-> #[[2]] & /@ Select[Subsets[rest, {2}], adjacentQ @@ # &];
graph = Graph[rest, edges];

FindClique[graph]
```

It computes all the pentagons, and defines `adjacentQ` to be the relation that says when two pentagons share two vertices but no edges. To symmetry-break a little, we choose $(1,2,3,4,5)$ and $(1,3,6,7,8)$ to be the first two pentagons, limiting our search to pentagons compatible with both of these. Then we build the graph in which two pentagons are adjacent when `adjacentQ` is true of them, and find a clique in this graph.

Comment: Thanks! It appears that your set has an automorphism group of order $55$. Reverse engineering this, and renumbering, we can take the pentagon $\{1,4,5,9,3\}$ and add 1 to each value, taking them mod $11$ to generate the remaining pentagons. Additionally, each value in $\{1,4,5,9,3\}$ is $4$ times the previous value, mod $11$.

Comment: One more fun observation. Take the five pentagons which share a common point, then remove that point and the edges to that point, so each of those pentagons now has only $4$ points with $3$ edges. Put those $5$ mangled pentagons together, and you get the Petersen graph!

Comment: A more general observation: if we start with $(1,2,3,4,5)$ and $(1,6,3,7,8)$ instead, we cannot - according to Mathematica - come up with $9$ more pairwise compatible pentagons. So any solution must be very symmetric: any pair of vertices is shared by two pentagons, one of which has it as an edge and the other as a diagonal. (Even though it could've been that some pairs occur $3$ times and some only once.)

Comment: That's also interesting. I couldn't find a combinatoric or even just counting argument to show that had to be the case. I was hoping the answer would be symmetric, so I'm glad it was.